# login.php, query result is always false

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, authentication

So I'm getting the same error and it drives me nuts.

> bool(false)
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/public/database.php >on line 21
>
> nicht eingeloggt

It seems that the result is always false although the select is correct. I'm new to PHP and databases so I'm not very into it yet. I hope someone of you can help me.

## `database.php`

```
    <?php
    
    class dbanbindung {
        private $connection;
        
        function __construct(){
            $this->connection = new mysqli("localhost", "wt1p2_nutzer", "12345678", "wt1p2");
            if($this->connection->connect_error){
                echo die($this->connection->connect_error);
            }
        
        }
        
        public function login($mail, $pwd) {
            $result = $this->connection->query("SELECT pwd FROM user WHERE mail ='$mail'");
            var_dump($result);
            // line 20
            if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
                $zeile = $result->fetch_assoc();
                $pw_result = $zeile["pwd"];
                
                if (strcmp($pw_result, $pwd) == 0) {
                    return TRUE;
                } else {
                    return FALSE;
                }
            }
            
            function __destruct(){ 
            $this->connection->close();
        }
    }
    
    ?>
```

## `login.php`

```
    <?php
    
    session_start();
    require ('database.php');
    $datenbank = new dbanbindung();
    
    $mail = $_POST["mail"];
    $pwd = hash('SHA512',$_POST["password"]);
    
    $login = $datenbank->login($mail,$pwd);
    
    if ($login) {
        echo ("login erfolgreich");
        
        $_SESSION["mail"] = $mail;
    }
    else {
        echo "nicht eingeloggt";
        // header("refresh:5;index.php#login");
    }
    
    ?>
```

## `index.php`

```
    <form method="POST" action="login.php">
                    <table border="0" id="table">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Mailadresse:</th>
                            <th><input type="text" name="mail" value="" placeholder="example@example.com"></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Passwort:</th>
                            <th><input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="******"></th>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <br />
                    <input type="submit" value="Login">
                </form>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords with a weak, high-speed hash like SHA or MD5**.

Comment: It's part of my studies and I will not use this for a real login.

Comment: That error usually happens when your database object (i.e. your connection) does not work.  Something is wrong with user password, port, connection, MySQL does not let you connect, ...  + the warning + SQL injection.  Also did you validate your query manually directly on the database, with the actual email you are using for your test?

Comment: I am not getting an error for false connection info, I tried to put wrong info in and it showed as such.

Comment: Check the values of $mail and $pwd in your login() function.  Then print your query to validate it.  Then run that query manually, to validate that you do have data in your table for that email.

Comment: Please add your HTML form. Is there a `method="POST"` attribute?

Comment: As @Nic3500 suggest, add `echo "SELECT pwd FROM user WHERE mail ='$mail'";` before `// line 20` to see what's going on

Comment: @pdog There's still no excuse to use broken techniques like SHA to hash passwords. The [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function is just as easy to use and it does it properly. You can later check with [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). Super easy and by default actually quite secure.

Comment: It's quite possible that [mysqli::error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) will tell you exactly what went wrong.

Comment: OK guys the query was wrong. the table was called users not user. Thank you for your great help. tadman my professor wanted it to be be SHA :/